# Is it possible to install SoX on XAMPP and how to use it?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, xampp, sox

I have installed sox on my windows. It is working on windows command prompt.

```
C:\Program Files\sox-14-4-2>sox audio1.vox audio2.wav
```

I don't know how to use this on php. Is it required to install this sox on xampp server too. If yes, then how to install this. Please let me know the whole procedure for converting vox file to wav.

I have tried this code but I did not get success.

```
echo shell_exec("c:/Program Files/sox-14-4-2/sox -y -i audio1.vox filenew.wav &");
```